# Generating repeated .pdf file when compiling LaTeX files with Sublime

Tags: viewers, preview, sublime-text

I can successfully compile my .tex file, but sublime always generates a new file.
That means when I generated a .pdf file named “one” after the first time compiling, there would be a file named "one 2" after my second time compiling and so on.

Besides, is there a way to preview my changes not compiling completely the file again?

Comment: Which SublimeText plugin do you use? LatexTools or Latexing? Are both Sublime and your plugin up to date? What is your OS?

Comment: LatexTools. They are all up to date(Sublime Text 3, LatexTools and Skim) My OS is Mac Sierra.